# How to use for each function inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have created a price list and would like to display the prices together underneath each product based on each sku value.

I have an array of data which is looped through and then pushed into the div.

```js
var arr = [
  {
"sku": "552",
"title": "orange",
"price": "1.55",
"per": 1
  },
  {
"sku": "552",
"title": "orange",
"price": "2.00",
"per": 2
  },
  {
"sku": "552",
"title": "orange",
"price": "3.50",
"per": 4
  },
  {
"sku": "551",
"title": "bannana",
"price": "0.95",
"per": 1
  },
  {
"sku": "551",
"title": "bannana",
"price": "2.20",
"per": 3
  },
  {
"sku": "544",
"title": "apple",
"price": "0.70",
"per": 1
  },
  {
"sku": "501",
"title": "pear",
"price": "1.15",
"per": 1
  }
];

            
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){

  var sku = arr[i].sku;
  var title = arr[i].title;
  var price = arr[i].price;
  var per = arr[i].per;

  var html = "<p>" + sku + " - " + title + "</p>";
  html +=   "<p><b>" + per + "</b> - " + price + "</p>";                    

  $("#div_1").append(html);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_1"></div>
```

I think I need to use the for each function...I have tried used a jquery foreach function inside the for loop but ended up with strange results.

```
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){

  var sku = arr[i].sku;
  var title = arr[i].title;
  var price = arr[i].price;
  var per = arr[i].per;

  var html = "<p>" + sku + " - " + title + "</p>";
  
  $.each(arr, function(key, value) {
  html +=   "<p><b>" + per + "</b> - " + price + "</p>";
});
                        

  $("#div_1").append(html);

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/amxkwgy9/

Comment: don't using var use let

Comment: There is no need to create an external jsfiddle. In fact jsfiddle is not very accessible for mobile devices. What exactly do you want to achieve with your second script, containing the `$.each()` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first group by SKU using groupedData then,iterate the arr array and add each product.

https://jsfiddle.net/grsn27hk/

```
 var groupedData = {};

        // Group the data by SKU
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var sku = arr[i].sku;

            if (!groupedData[sku]) {
                groupedData[sku] = [];
            }

            groupedData[sku].push(arr[i]);
        }

        // Display the grouped data
        for (var sku in groupedData) {
            if (groupedData.hasOwnProperty(sku)) {
                var products = groupedData[sku];
                var skuTitle = products[0].sku + " - " + products[0].title;

                var html = "<p>" + skuTitle + "</p>";

                for (var j = 0; j < products.length; j++) {
                    var product = products[j];
                    html += "<p><b>" + product.per + "</b> - " + product.price + "</p>";
                }

                $("#div_1").append(html);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to web development, I would recommend you to use a simple templating engine like mustache, that would make your life easy :) Link https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/

Looking at your input it looks like you need the right data coming from the backend API resonse itself.

But since you already have the input you should be able to solve the problem with a groupby functionality, in that case you can use JS reduce by title. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Here is an example:

```
const result = products.reduce((x, y) => {
  (x[y.title] = x[y.title] || []).push(y);
    return x;
}, {});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k1smzcnv/1/

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't really made use of any jQuery specific features I took the liberty of preparing an alternative solution using Vanilla JavaScript:

```js
var arr = [
  {
"sku": "552",
"title": "orange",
"price": "1.55",
"per": 1
  },
  {
"sku": "552",
"title": "orange",
"price": "2.00",
"per": 2
  },
  {
"sku": "552",
"title": "orange",
"price": "3.50",
"per": 4
  },
  {
"sku": "551",
"title": "bannana",
"price": "0.95",
"per": 1
  },
  {
"sku": "551",
"title": "bannana",
"price": "2.20",
"per": 3
  },
  {
"sku": "544",
"title": "apple",
"price": "0.70",
"per": 1
  },
  {
"sku": "501",
"title": "pear",
"price": "1.15",
"per": 1
  }
];

const res=arr.reduce((a,c)=>{ // group according to sku:
(a[c.sku]=a[c.sku]||{title:c.title,prices:[]}).prices.push([c.per,c.price]);
 return a;
},{});
// map over all keys and values of res:
let html=Object.entries(res).map(([sku,c])=>`<p>${sku} - ${c.title}</p><p>prices:<br>${c.prices.map(([per,price])=>`<b>${per}</b> - ${price}`).join("<br>\n")}`).join("</p>\n");                    

// Append the generated HTML to #div_1:
document.getElementById("div_1").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",html);
```

```html
<div id="div_1"></div>
```